# Experiment has totally wrong conversion rate

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have set up a Google Analytics Experiment the following way:

```
<!-- Load the Content Experiment JavaScript API client for the experiment -->
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=REMOVED>"></script>
<script>
    // Ask Google Analytics which variation to show the user.
    var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();

    $(function(){

        if (chosenVariation == 1) {
            ouibounce(document.getElementById('exit-dialog'), { sitewide: true, cookieExpire: 10, callback: function(){
                ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Open');
            } });
            $("#exit-dialog").on("click", function(){
                $("#exit-dialog").hide();
                ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Hide', 'Background');
            });

            $("#exit-dialog .no-thanks").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#exit-dialog").hide();
                ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Hide', 'Button');
            });

            $("#exit-dialog > div").on("click", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code is on the bottom of my .
This is what I see in Analytics:

[image: GA Experiment]

The problem is that this same goal has a <1% conversion normally. How can the experiment be getting it so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from you example, but common problem is early binding event listeners. I mean you attach on click event before the DOM element is loaded.

I suggest you wrap onclick event setter with function and call this function after experiment is fully loaded. So you will call it like a callback:

### Setter:

```
<script>
    var setExperimentEvents = function(){
        // Ask Google Analytics which variation to show the user.
        var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();

        $(function(){

            if (chosenVariation == 1) {
                ouibounce(document.getElementById('exit-dialog'), { sitewide: true, cookieExpire: 10, callback: function(){
                    ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Open');
                } });
                $("#exit-dialog").on("click", function(){
                    $("#exit-dialog").hide();
                    ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Hide', 'Background');
                });

                $("#exit-dialog .no-thanks").on("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#exit-dialog").hide();
                    ga('send', 'event', 'ExitDialog', 'Hide', 'Button');
                });

                $("#exit-dialog > div").on("click", function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### Experiment page bottom:

```
<script>

    try{
     setExperimentEvents();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      ga('send', 'event', 'Error', 'Experiment', 'Failed to load',cxApi.chooseVariation());
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The OP wrote "This code is on the bottom of my". Assuming he meant the bottom of his page early binding of event listeners is probably not the problem.

Comment: But when you do experiments, you fetch new content usually asynchronously, so event you have code in bottom of the page, you are still too fast. I think that the best way is when measurement is part of tested code.

Comment: You're probably right (I certainly agree that it's "hard to say from the example").

Comment: From my experience it was the most common problem with A/B tests

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the pageview event was sent before the variant was chosen, and thus was not sent to the server unless an event was fired on the page.